# How to infinitly loop through array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to define an infinite loop for array iteration and for each iteration it should assign the value to a single variable.

For example, the 1st value item will be pin-1.png. For the 2nd iteration, the i value will be pin-2.png and so on...

How can i do this?

My current code:

```
var markers = [
    ['images/pushpins/pin-1.png'],
    ['images/pushpins/pin-2.png'],
    ['images/pushpins/pin-3.png'],
    ['images/pushpins/pin-4.png'],
    ['images/pushpins/pin-5.png']
];


function randomize(){
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    marker_image = i;
  }
}

function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      icon: marker_image,
      optimized: false,
      //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    }));
  }, timeout);
}
```

Comment: What should the 6th item be?

Comment: How much marker you want to add?

Comment: Why would you want an infinite loop? It will just freeze your browser.

Comment: @Mureinik there is no 6th item... the array should start iterating again..

Comment: @Mitul there is no limit for marker it goes on continue... for now lets say 300.

Comment: How you call the addMarkerWithTimeout() function

Comment: Just replace `i < markers.length` statement with `true` (in `for` loop)

Comment: markers is an array with an array with strings. your timeout pushes objects to markers, so markers contains different type of items?

Comment: @MithunRaikar - arrays don't 'do' anything, they just are. What are you actually trying to achieve - don't tell me how you think you should go about it - just say what the expected outcome or purpose is. As written, you question makes little sense.

Comment: OK so you want to show the random marker on tha map right with infinite loop

Comment: @Mitul right. to use random marker icons on map.

Comment: @MithunRaikar I have added code for to get the random number from the 0-4 so you can call the function in your infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the bellow function which will give the random number between 0-5 so you can get random number each call

```
function getInonPos(){
    return parseInt(Math.random() * 5)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your randomize function to:

```
function randomize() {
    marker_image = Math.random() * markers.length | 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **setTimeout** inside **setTimeout** like a background thread or **setInterval** if needed

first declare you anonymous function as a function or assign it to a variable like

```
var markerFunction = function() {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      icon: marker_image,
      optimized: false,
      //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
    }));

    //write some condition to stop the loop
    //you can call randomize() here if needed
    window.setTimeout(markerFunction, timeout);

};


window.setTimeout(markerFunction, timeout);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const loopOverArray = (arr) => {
  let index = -1;

  const getNextElementFromArray = () => {
    index++;
    const nextIndex = index % arr.length;
    return arr[nextIndex];
  };

  return getNextElementFromArray;
};

const getNextElement = loopOverArray([1, 2, 3]);

console.log(getNextElement()); // 1
console.log(getNextElement()); // 2
console.log(getNextElement()); // 3
console.log(getNextElement()); // 1
```